# Why can't Doxygen resolve most of the methods in my call graph?

Tags: doxygen

Take a look at [this call graph](https://thejohnfreeman.github.io/rippled/classripple_1_1InboundLedgersImp.html#a4410398a5eaebf565d5355feba32dd9b). Now look at the [source of that function](https://thejohnfreeman.github.io/rippled/InboundLedgers_8cpp_source.html#l00069) and all the calls to methods of `InboundLedger`, through the `shared_ptr<InboundLedger>` named `inbound`. Notice how the call graph mentions none of those methods. Notice how the source doesn't cross-reference hyperlink any of those methods (unlike the methods of `app_`, for example).

If we look at a [method](https://thejohnfreeman.github.io/rippled/InboundLedger_8cpp_source.html#l00176) of `InboundLedger`, we can see that Doxygen can resolve and hyperlink other methods of `InboundLedger` that it calls (`tryDB()`, `isDone()`, `done()`), so the problem isn't just a general "Doxygen can't resolve `InboundLedger`".

[This](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/rippled/tree/2aa217c47a372f4df94cb501a8c28800dbc8a248) is the source tree that was used to build that documentation. [This](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/rippled/blob/2aa217c47a372f4df94cb501a8c28800dbc8a248/docs/Doxyfile) is the Doxyfile in that tree. I used Doxygen 1.8.18, built from source, [commit b4b47b3919650d7350acc9fe59becaee4a3d5ff5](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/tree/b4b47b3919650d7350acc9fe59becaee4a3d5ff5). I had started my journey on 1.8.13, the version packaged for Ubuntu Eoan.

I have enabled `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT`, so Doxygen should be able to see through `std::shared_ptr`. In fact, I have tried to build a minimum reproducible example with this same Doxyfile and failed; three files with `InboundLedger`, `InboundLedgers`, and `InboundLedgersImp` was able to resolve the call graph as I expected, with the help of `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT`.

I have tried changing various settings, but they af nothing:

- Upped `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` to 200
- Set every `EXTRACT_*` setting to `YES`
- Unset `TAGFILES`
- Set `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING` to `YES`

Comment: A lot of external links. please add a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a tar or zip) .  Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent. Regarding the Doxyfile is is sufficient  it is enough to add the output of `doxygen -x`. The "shared_ptr<..>" is probably a "newer" concept that is not yet in doxygen. In case you think it is a bug in doxygen you can create an issue at: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: I almost feel like you didn't read my question at all. You can get the source and configuration in a tar from GitHub. SO isn't going to host a tarball, and I've used links to a specific commit, not a branch, so that's as persistent as it gets. I have been unsuccessful at shrinking this example. `shared_ptr` _is_ in Doxygen, via [`BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT`](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/b4b47b3919650d7350acc9fe59becaee4a3d5ff5/src/stlsupport.cpp#L41). I'll upload the trace to a Gist.

Comment: I did read the question, SO won't host the tar file that is clear, that is also why I added the doxygen issue possibility. A big reduction, compared to the complete project tree, for an issue would already be just to include the required files as indicated in the tags like `INPUT`, `IMAGE_PATH`, `INCLUDE_PATH`, ... in the tar file

Comment: I was able to distill a small example. I think it's a bug: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7680